# Analyzing MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

Here is the problem:

[image]

And here is my solution and I want to check if it is correct or not:

```
VDS > VGS - VTN  --> device is operating in saturation mode.

VDS = VD - VS = 5 - (-5) = 10 V.

VGS = VG - VS = 0 - (-5) = 5 V.
```

Comment: You can't assume \$V_s\$ to be -5 volts, because there must be some voltage drop across the current source.

Comment: Can you help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the equation $$I_d=K_n\cdot(V_{GS}-V_{TN})^2\cdot(1+\lambda\cdot V_{DS})$$
which simplifies to $$I_d=K_n\cdot(V_{GS}-V_{TN})^2$$ as \$\lambda=0\$. \$I_d\$ is set to 1 mA by the current source, so we can solve it for \$V_{GS}\$.

$$1=0.5\cdot(V_{GS}-1.2)^2$$
$$V_{GS}=\sqrt2+1.2\approx2.614V$$

As the gate is grounded, the source potential \$V_S\$ equals -2.614 volts. $$V_{DS}=5-(-2.614)=7.614 V$$

Your assumption was good, the transistor is in saturation mode.

Comment: Thanks but how did you verify that it was in saturation mode?

Comment: Look at the first sentence of your attempted solution!

Comment: But I think it should be `0.5 kn` since we assumed that it is in saturation mode. Right?

Comment: In my opinion that factor is already present in the given \$K_n\$ value.